# How to use the -mlongcall GCC flag in Rust?

Tags: gcc, rust, llvm, target

I am trying to run a Rust program on a powerpc arch. When I build my code in C I use the flag `-mlongcall`.

How can I use this flag for my Rust program? In general, it would be nice to know if I can use flags that I know from GCC in my Rust build.

Comment: `--help` will give you all you need to know

Comment: I dont think it helps in this situation...

Comment: You haven't even explained what you want to achieve, so how could we possibly tell you what helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for the -mlongcall flag is to use the flag: `-Ctarget-features=+longcall` as suggested in this issue: [add mlongcall flag to rustc](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/65403)